# ¿Existe algún término que englobe una serie de conceptos económicos como "factura", "nómina", "domiciliación", etc.?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

Estoy haciendo un pequeño módulo de contabilidad, que permita a la empresa tener un control del flujo de caja (*cash flow*) registrando las previsiones de pagos y cobros a futuro.

Estoy montando un pequeño esquema de base de datos (muy sencillo), tal que así:

```
PROYECTOS            FACTURAS          MOVIMIENTOS
---------            --------          -----------
ID                   ID                ID
...                  ID_PROYECTO       ID_FACTURA
                     CONCEPTO          FECHA
                     ...               CUANTÍA
                                       ...
```

De esta forma se pueden asociar facturas a proyectos, y para cada factura puede haber una serie de movimientos bancarios previstos (en caso de que la factura se pague en varios plazos, por ejemplo), definidos por la cuantía y la fecha de cada movimiento. Sin embargo, me llega el economista y me dice que en la tabla de facturas va a haber diferentes conceptos, y no solamente facturas. Así, puede haber:

- Facturas.
- Nóminas.
- Domiciliaciones.
- Cuotas de préstamos.
- Devoluciones.
- ...

Como no soy economista, lo único que se me ocurre son términos globales como *objeto* o *concepto*, aunque este último lo pensaba reservar para el campo con la descripción de la factura (tal y como se ve en el esquema).

Así pues, ¿existe algún término económico que refleje este tipo de operaciones bancarias de forma más profesional?

Comment: Me parece que "tipo (de documento/transacción)" sería la mejor palabra, a menos que exista algo más específicamente bancario (por lo que no lo pongo como respuesta y solo comentario)

Comment: @guifa pues no te creas que "transacciones" es un mal nombre para esa tabla...

Comment: “Transacciones” es como lo tenemos nosotros en el sistema que usamos, pero como no sé mucho de contabilidad no sé si es adecuado o no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al final hablando con el economista, resulta que un nombre que parece apropiado para la tabla lo había planteado yo ya en el texto de la pregunta sin darme cuenta: ***Operaciones***. A fin de cuentas, cualquier movimiento de dinero corresponde a una operación bancaria.

Comment: Lo mejor que pudiste hacer fue hablar con el economista/cliente. A estas cosas se le pueden dar muchos nombres y normalmente cada empresa, contable, administrativo, incluso cada software y más de un libro técnico, usa un nombre diferente. Es mejor usar el nombre al que esté acostumbrado el que va a usar el software.